# Windows version of ''mkdir folder{1..100}/subfolder"

Tags: windows, command-line

I am new to using the command line, especially in Windows. I would like to generate a (large) number of folders, say 100 of them, each with a subfolder of the same name. In Linux, I used

```
mkdir folder{1..100}/subfolder
```

but the same command does not work in Windows. It will generate a folder of the name "folder{1..100}", which is not what I want.

Comment: mkdir for windows has no -p option

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like That's true but `-p` is not mentioned in the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such powerful command expansion in wincows cmd line processor as in *nix world. However, you could use `for` loop.

Batch file syntax:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (start,step,end) DO md folder%%i
```

Interactive invocation:

```
FOR /L %i IN (start,step,end) DO md folder%i
```

Comment: Note that it's spelled `%i` when running interactively.

Comment: The question mentions the creation of a subfolder as well, can you create the folder and subfolder in a single command or do you need another `FOR /L %i IN (start,step,end) DO md folder%i\subfolder` ?

Comment: @Mokubai MD creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.